# Ставить ли знак препинания??

Tags: пунктуация

Нужен ли знак препинания???
"Тип рекламной конструкции: баннер."

Comment: двоеточие или тире

Answer (score 3):

Какой "знак препинания" Вы имеете в виду? 
Точка в конце? Нет, она не нужна. Если это конец предложения, то точка ставится **после** кавычек.

> двоеточие или тире

Скорее тире. Сейчас эти знаки считаются отчасти взаимозаменяемыми, императивного правила нет. 
Но если исходить из того, что у Вас нет перечисления и фраза явно неполная, то тире смотрится более подходящим.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы не считать это выражение предложением вида сущ. И.п. - сущ. И.п., в котором между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится тире. Как говорится в Грамматике 80, лексико-семантическое наполнение компонентов свободное. В данном случае в предложении содержится информация о том, что субъект (тип рекламной продукции) является баннером.